# Determining the string formats for datetime-timezone

Tags: time-date, logging

When loading a `.log` file I get the message

```
Warning (emacs): Failed to determine system timezone; consider customizing ‘datetime-timezone’ variable
```

Going to the customization menu, the options are not evident:

```
Hide Datetime Timezone: nil
    State : STANDARD.
   Default timezone for date-time formatting and parsing. Hide
   Leave unset to let the library auto-determine it from your OS
   when necessary.
Groups: Datetime
```

Lines that also appear in the [source](https://github.com/doublep/datetime/blob/master/datetime.el)

```
(defcustom datetime-timezone nil
  "Default timezone for date-time formatting and parsing.
Leave unset to let the library auto-determine it from your OS
when necessary."
  :group 'datetime
  :type  'symbol)
```

1. What is the appropriate way to set my timezone on macOS so that `datetime-timezone` would inherit it without a duplication in `~/.emacs`.
2. Failing that, what is the format for this customization? (For some reason, `C-h i` does not include a menu for `datetime` in my installation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Zone-Rules.html) it should be determined with the TZ environment variable :

> The default time zone is determined by the TZ environment variable.
>   [...] For example, you can tell Emacs to default to Universal Time
>   with (setenv "TZ" "UTC0"). If TZ is not in the environment, Emacs uses
>   system wall clock time, which is a platform-dependent default time
>   zone.

Have you tried to set this variable ?

You should be able to set it from Emacs, using *eval-expression* (M-:) :

```
(setenv "TZ" "America/New_York")
```

or you can set it at launch before running *emacs* command from your shell :

```sh
$ TZ="America/New_York" emacs
```

Tested successfully on Linux, but can't tell for Mac OS.

Comment: Can you add the relevant part from documentation to your post, as well as an example that works as expected?